# Creating accessible tooltips for a web site

Tags: javascript, css, accessibility, tooltip, section508

Is there a best practice for making tooltip type functionality accessible to people with accessibility needs?

I am interested in jquery tooltip and have found a few others but I am thinking twice before spending anytime as I am concerned about accessibility compliance of these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `title` attribute of relevant elements to provide information. However, note that although most browsers show these as tooltips, they're not required to. Several jQuery tooltip libraries use the `title` attribute to grab tooltip text, so I would look into any that do this.

Comment: Adding the title attribute will not make the tool tip accessible.

Comment: How so? It's pretty well supported by screen readers http://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/articles/WE05/forms.html