# Accessibility for CSS-only tooltip

Tags: css, accessibility

I accessibility guidance for my CSS-only tooltip — http://chantastic.github.io/tip.css/

This is how you use it:

```
<span data-tip-content="this is a tip" data-has-tip>Hover here</span>
```

#### The current API

To avoid the browsers default rendering of `title`, I'm using `data-tip-content` for tooltip text. By doing that, I'm also losing the accessibility benefits of `title` ([Related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3720107/creating-accessible-tooltips-for-a-web-site)).

#### My Current Work around

I'd like to add `aria-label` as a content source, making use look like this:

```
<span aria-label="this is a tip" data-has-tip>Hover here</span>
```

#### My Question

Does `aria-label` make sense in this case? Is there an accessibility interest that this will not cover?

I am very new to accessibility and would appreciate experience-based feedback. Thank you.

---

If you think there is a better solution, please consider these constraints:

- **CSS-only**. Many JS-tooltips simply remove and restore the `title`-attr on `mousenter/mouseleave`. I'm not interested in a JS solution.
- **No Additional Markup**. This library is intended to be minimal and simple. It uses `:after`, `:before`, and `content` to avoid the requirement for additional markup blocks.
- **Two-Attribute API**. This library only requires the addition of 2 attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`aria-label`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-label) attribute specifies a *label* for the element, typically an accessible name for an input element that would otherwise lack an explicit label, because the user is expected to infer its role from the visual context. Although its description refers to the HTML `title` attribute and tooltips, it’s not really meant to be used for things like CSS tooltips. Rather, it is useful for labelling elements instead of using the `title` attribute, which has some drawbacks in such use.

However, there is unfortunately no ARIA attribute that would be more suitable. There is odd asymmetry: ARIA has `aria-label` for direct labeling and `aria-labelledby` for indirect labeling, i.e. for specifying an element that contains a label for the current element, but for descriptions, there is just the indirect [`aria-describedby`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-describedby).

So this boils down to using `aria-label`, given your current approach and markup. In a different approach, where the tooltip text is element content and not an attribute value, you could use `aria-describedby`.

P.S. The attribute `data-has-tip` looks redundant here, since you can use, both in CSS and in scripting, just the presence of a `data-tip-content` attribute instead.

Comment: Thanks for the great feedback. It looks like I'll need to solve the accessibly problem on the markup side.

Comment: Regarding the API, the `data-has-tip` can be used to pass styling constraints like "left right top and bottom"